# Firbird DB multiple connections problem using BDE+ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, firebird, bde

I have a set of applications working with InterBase databases. Now I try to migrate it to Firebird 4 instead.

I migrated the DB and installed Firebird ODBC driver (2.00.05.156) and set connection. BDE see this ODBC connection and an app could connect and work by BDE (via ODBC driver) successfully.

The issue is when I try to run another app (or second instance of the same app) that connecting to the same DB (also by BDE with ODBC driver) it's failed with error: "[ODBC Firebird Driver]File Database is not found".

In other words, it looks like only one BDE connection using the ODBC driver can be accepted to the same DB.

OS: Win10/Win11

I tried to change the parameter "safe thread" in Firebird ODBC driver - didn't help.

Is it possible to avoid this problem by keeping BDE usage (the apps are huge and it will be very difficult to replace the BDE)?

Comment: Did you try to use BDE native Interbase database type instead of ODBC (creating gds32.dll using instlicent utility)? Did you try to use TCP connection string? Firebird version 3+ is much different from any Interbase you ever used. You must learn it from scratch starting from Quick Start Guide https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-rdbms/

Comment: Which client library does the ODBC driver point to? Are you using the correct path to the database file? Are you using a remote connection string (including hostname), or a local connection string (filepath only)?

Comment: The problem was with missing TCP connection. After add localhost, the problem was fixed. Thanks!